# Using an interface as type parameter to generic method

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a Unity3d game using C#, and we have a lot of situations where we need to access a particular member (say, `int health`) of a `GameObject`. We do this using code like:

```
GameObject obj;
if(obj.GetComponent<Player>() != null) {
    obj.GetComponent<Player>().health--;
}
else if(obj.GetComponent<Robot>() != null) {
    obj.GetComponent<Robot>().health--;
}
// more painful code
```

What I'd like to do is have all such classes implement an interface like `IHealth`, and then do `obj.GetComponent<IHealth>().health--;`. Is this possible, though? I've looked around and it seems like I can't use an interface as a type parameter.

Comment: That works fine.  Did you try it?

Comment: @SLaks No, interfaces can only have methods or properties, not fields.

Comment: You may want to consider catching the result that you use in the if block so you're not calling GetComponent twice per object type.

Comment: @Servy: Yes; those should be properties.

Comment: If GameObject is a struct, not a class, then when you box it to the interface you're getting a copy and mutating the copy, not the actual object, so it won't do what you want.  On top of that, an interface can only have methods or properties, not fields.

Comment: @SLaks Keep in mind this is a game, so it's probably XNA; chances are they aren't going to be properties.

Comment: @Peter AFAIK, `GetComponent` via generics does not support `interface`, but I think the non-generic one does. Try `(IHealth)GetComponent(typeof(IHealth))` to see. Though IMO, this way is even worse. I have not tried `abstract` classes though, perhaps they would work and might just fit in with your program design. (also, do you assign these components in the Unity IDE or at runtime? I suspect, at least, if assigned in the editor, they'll be attached via their full final type and not accessible via a base class or interface anyway)

Comment: From Chris Sinclair's comment it seems this is very specifically a Unity platform issue, not a `C#` or `generics` one per se, because as we have all pointed out `C#` as no inherent limitation against using interfaces as generic type arguments. Perhaps you should update this question and tags to reflect this, and/or clarify that `GameObject.GetComponent` is a platform-defined function, not just a random method you made up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just have a component `Health`. Then attach that to your GameObject, have a `RequiresComponent` annotation on any scripts that need health, then get it by `GetComponent<Health>();` (cache it inside the same-object scripts in a private variable)

If you have multiple 'stats' that are always together, you could make it easier like

```
public class Status : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float health;
    public float armor;
}
```

I've found with unity, this is a surprisingly common 'problem'. Not sure if it's a problem because this thinking can really help with some problems...

Comment: That sounds great; I didn't know about `RequiresComponent`. I'll use that in future projects.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is not easy, and likely not a good idea, to do. The issue is that `GetComponent<T>` expects the type parameter `T` to be derived from `Component` (and of course, Unity doesn't document this). I would need to make `Robot`, `Player`, etc. all derive from an abstract class which itself inherits from `Component` (through `MonoBehaviour`), and contains information about health and other fields. I doubt that this is worth it; it might lead to just as much messy code in other places.

Answer (score 0):

As SLaks noted, interfaces are perfectly acceptable as generic type parameters. If your problem is accessing a field via an interface, then I would suggest simply changing your field to a property. If for some reason you absolutely must keep that field, just provide a wrapping property which implicitly implements the interface. If the problem is that the field and the property have the exact same name (including casing), you can explicitly implement the interface:

```
public interface IHealth { int Health { get; set; } }

// Change to a property
public class Ogre : IHealth { public int Health { get; set; } }

// Casing is different, so interface can be implemented implicitly
public class Player : IHealth {
    int health;
    public int Health { get { return health; } set { health = value; } }
}

// Name collision with Pascal casing, so implement explicitly
public class Robot : IHealth {
    int Health;
    int IHealth.Health { get { return Health; } set { Health = value; } }
}

// Later
GameObject obj;
var o = obj.GetComponent<IHealth>();
if (o != null) o.Health--;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a fundamental design issue because your consuming code needs to know about each type. If you're taking the same action regardless of the type, then just use good ol' polymorphism:

```
public class Player: IHealth {}

public class Robot: IHealth {}
```

Instead of a bunch of `if` statements, remove the generic parameter from GetComponent and have it return an IHealth object:

```
public IHealth GetComponent()
{
    // return IHealth object here
}
```

In your calling code:

```
obj.GetComponent().DecreaseHealth();
```